# convert string to json and bind in List<classobject>

Tags: java, json, deserialization, model-binding

I have following string

```
string strFriends = {"data":[{"name":"Paras Dave","id":"535228534"},{"name":"Pradip Mehta","id":"537004435"},{"name":"Rajni Vanza","id":"545844068"}],"paging":{"next": "0"}};
```

Now i wanted to bind data part in to the friend list object

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<FriendModel> friends= serializer.Deserialize<List<FriendModel>>(strFriends);
```

but the above will return 0 records.

Model

```
 public class FriendModel
    {
        string id { set; get; }
        string name { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: Why the {'data' : part? Your JSON represents an object that contains a list, not a list itself.

Comment: this will return by the Facebook api and i wanted only data part

Answer (score 0):

JSON got some beautiful objects themselves you want to use them.

http://json.org/java/